# Wordpress Blog Backend or Login Under a Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming, subdomain

I have a domain where I need the `siteurl` and `home` options to be the domain url **Without** a sub domain. But I need to login to the backend of wordpress under a subdomain.

I tried changing the `siteurl` and `home` options but that auto redirects me to the non-subdomain once I login. Changing just one of the options causes the resources (css & js) on the blog page to be linked to the subdomain.

Is there anyway around this problem to allow me to login to a subdomain, but still have the blog/frontend point to non-subdomain?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42237/moving-wp-admin-to-a-different-to-a-subdomain/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered for me by: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42237/moving-wp-admin-to-a-different-to-a-subdomain/

Thanks to @b__ for the comment to point me to it.

Also I wanted to close this as duplicate of that question but it won't let me unless the question is on Stackoverflow so I decided to just answer it myself with this info.